# How does the Essence Attribute limit work with artifacts?

Tags: exalted, exalted-2e

In 2nd edition exalted you can only get an attribute past 5 dots if your essence is also past 5. How does this work with artifacts?

For Example

> Crown of Thunder(Artifact 5): Once Attuned (10 motes) it increased her physical attributes by 3 dots.

If an essence 3, Solar who had strength 5 attuned to this helmet would it increase his Strength to 8 or would it be capped at 5 until his essence was raised?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Artefacts Allow Exceeding Limits

2nd edition corebook, page 275:

> Elder Exalts can raise their Essence, Attributes and Abilities above 5 using the same formula as described previously, but they must first increase their permanent Essence score. For example, an Essence of 6 allows characters to raise Attributes and Abilities to 6. Solar Exalts **can increase Abilities and Attribute above this maximum with rare artifacts or other supernatural means**, but they **may never spend experience to do so** without first raising the Essence score.

The rule is meant to limit *buying attributes with Experience Points*, not prevent use of Artefacts (or Charms!) that increase said attributes.

Answer (score -1):

I can think of very few effects that raise an character's attributes but if I were to make the call in my own games I would take a few different factors into account:

1. The character's power; Mortals have no business wielding the power of the gods, if I'm feeling charitable I would only allow them to reach their cap and limit gains by their Essence rating. If not I'd say the power starts tearing their fragile bodies and souls apart. Ghosts, half-castes and other more supernatural beings have less to fear and more to gain.
2. The power of the effect; the Crown of Thunder is a rank 5 artifact, meant to bestow earthshaking power to the wearer, it would be a letdown if it could only bring you to peak mortal performance and not push you beyond that. Lesser artifacts or magics I would certainly restrict more, but what is a rank 3 or lower artifact even doing increasing your attributes?

The only absolute rule that I would stick to is the hard cap of attributes at 10.

Comment: This answer is a good one in regards to Mortals, however I am looking for one specifically to the exalted and solar exalted at that.